# A factoring conversion

Tags: factoring

There was a comment [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2274/permanents-approximation-and-connection-to-integer-factorization) that " It is possible in principle to reduce the factorization of a $256$-bit number (which is computable in TFNP) to the Permanent on a matrix of dimension $N\times N$ where $N\leq c\cdot256^c + c$ for some hopefully small constant $c$. However the computation of a nice upper bound on $c$ would probably take substantial effort. It's possible c is no more than 2 or 3."

Is it possible to convert factoring integers to calculating permanent? That is given $\log N$ bit integer to factor, how can one reduce factoring such an integer to calculating permanent of $(\log n)^c\times(\log n)^c$ matrix for a fixed $c$?

---

I also ask if computing $a(a+1)(a+2)\dots(a+n)$ with $a\in\Bbb N$ is also easy (done in $\log^cn$ steps if permanent of $N\times N$ matrix is easy (done in $N^c$ steps). Note that at $a=1$ we have $n!$, and permanent of all $1$ matrix needs $n\times n$ size and hence needs $n^c$ time even if permanent is easy.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P-completeness_of_01-permanent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The language of tuples $\langle n,i,j,b \rangle$ such that the $j$th bit of the $i$th prime factor of $n$ is $b$ is in NP. In particular, it is in #P. More accurately, there is a #P algorithm that on input $\langle n,i,j \rangle$ gives the $j$th bit of the $i$th prime factor of $n$ (either $0$ or $1$). Since the permanent is #P-complete, we can reduce this algorithm to the computation of some polysize permanent.

Comment: Actually problem you stated seems to be in $\mathsf{NP\cap coNP}$. I assume you are ordering prime factors of $n$ in terms of size and so you refer as $i$th prime factor of $n$. Does this have any issue with what you state later? Also what is the $\#P$ algorithm that gives $j$th bit of $i$th prime factor of $n$?

Comment: The distinction between $\mathsf{NP}$ and $\mathsf{coNP}$ disappears when looking at it from the angle of $\mathsf{\#P}$. Your assumption regarding the meaning of $i$ is correct. The $\mathsf{\#P}$ algorithm guesses and verifies the factoring, but only accepts factorings in which the $j$th bit of the $i$th prime factor is $1$.

Comment: So there is no explicit way to give the permanent?

Comment: The proof of $\mathsf{\#P}$-completeness of the permanent gives an algorithm for constructing the permanent. Anything more explicit would be masochistic.

Comment: But this is more like mastrubation. You really have nothing except your imagination on the existence $\#P$ algorithm (imagination comes from its existance).

Comment: @Turbo No, I gave you an algorithm, using the standard amount of detail.

Comment: Ok I think I get it now. Actually I want something else. I ask if computing $a(a+1)(a+2)\dots(a+n)$ with $a\in\Bbb N$ is also easy (done in $\log^cn$ steps if permanent of $N\times N$ matrix is easy (done in $N^c$ steps). Note that at $a=1$ we have $n!$, and permanent of all $1$ matrix needs $n\times n$ size and hence needs $n^c$ time even if permanent is easy. Ryan williams's comment was factorial is easy if permanent is easy.

Comment: If you have another question, I encourage you to ask it as a new question.

Comment: Ok I will do that

Comment: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32790/complexity-of-product-of-numbers-if-permanent-is-easy